# Laravel 5.4 - Override API 'throttle:60,1'

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, throttling

I'm writing a lot of API to get and store data.
I like the default `throttle` option:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

to limit the request to 60 per minute; but for some route (es: `POST`), I'd like to increase this value.

I tried to set `'throttle:500,1'` on route Middleware like below:

```
Route::group(function () {
        Route::get('semaphore/1',        ['uses' => 'App\Api\V1\DBs\SemaphoreController@index']);
        Route::post('semaphore/1',       ['uses' => 'App\Api\V1\DBs\SemaphoreController@store',        'middleware' => 'WriteToDatabaseMiddleware', 'throttle:500,1']);
});
```

but it does not work.

Any idea?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I noticed that the `'throttle:500,1'` used in the `api.php` route will be set AFTER the default `'throttle:60,1'` specified into `Kernel.php` file; then, It doesn't work.

Logging the process execution, the first call is:

```
Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests -> handle
```

from `Kernel.php` has `maxAttempts=60`.

Then, the second call is:

```
Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests -> handle
```

from `api.php` has `maxAttempts=500`.

In others words, the `throttle:500,1` in the `api.php` file do not override the `throttle:60,1` in the `Kernel.php` file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Current answer

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16786), the throttle middleware **should not** be used "twice" (like you want to do that). There are only two ways how to deal with your current problem "correctly":

1. Write **an own** throttling middleware

or

2. Define the throttle middleware **separately** for each route (group)

---

### Old answer

You set the middleware key wrong! When declaring multiple middleware to use, create a new array for them

```
['middleware' => ['WriteToDatabaseMiddleware','throttle:500,1']]
```

**EDIT:** Because of the middleware order, you should set your kernel throttle to the *highest value* you want to use, and all other routes that should have a *lower throttle value* to the corresponding ones.

Comment: You are welcome @vlauciani
It'd be great if you'd accept the answer because it solved your problem :)

Comment: I test on my code but It doesn't work; I've update my Question with the investigation.

Comment: @vlauciani Well, then you should change your Kernel values to `throttle:500,1` (to the higher one), and all other routes that should have throttle to `throttle:60,1`. This should work with the request order.

Comment: yes, your solution is my idea... the problem is that with this approach all route will be set to `500`; the I've to remember to set to `60` every new route. I prefer to have a standard value (ex: `60`) and override to `500` only specific route.

Comment: @vlauciani I see your point. Anyway, because it looks like the problem is on the Laravel site, better create an issue on their GitHub repo. I can't do more here :|

Comment: @vlauciani Update

Comment: Thank you @manniL, I read you "**Current answer**" now. Ok, It clarifies the operation; I think the solution is to create my own throttling middleware. Thank you again.

Comment: You cannot use independent throttles on different groups in Laravel 5.x: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/28856

Answer (score 4):

In laravel 6 you can use prefix for prevent with global throttle.
use `'throttle:5,1,prefix'`

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'contact-us', 'middleware' => 'throttle:5,1,contact-form',], function () {
    Route::post('/', 'ContactUsController@store');
});
```

[Allow multiple throttles by naming](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/28856)

Comment: Laravel 5.9? Do you mean Laravel 6. After 5.8 Laravel went to semantic versioning starting at version 6.0.0.

Comment: Hi Andrew, version 5.9 is wrong and fix my answer.  
if you want use prefix in throttle middleware, this pull request may help you [Allow multiple throttles by naming](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/28856).

Answer (score 4):

None of the current answers explain Laravel 5.x behaviour. In that version every instance of "throttle" uses the same bucket. So if you place a throttle command in two separate locations it affects every instance.

Consider:

```
// User can email 5 times an hour
Route::post('/email', 'Ctrl@email')->middleware('throttle:5,60');
// User can search 100 times an hour
Route::get('/search', 'Ctrl@search')->middleware('throttle:100,60);
```

If a user searches 5 times in a 5 minute period, they will not able to email in the next hour.

In Laravel 5.x there is no way around this. In Laravel 6 onwards [they added the ability to name throttles](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/28856), giving them separate buckets.